# Group records by UserID, select where on one column value and sum another

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Using SQL in MySQLWorkbench I'd like to group records by 'UserID', 
select only the records that match where 'Weeks' are in(5,6,7,8) and sum the values for each user in 'Score'.

The records are actually stored in two tables that I am joining, a lineup table and lineup history table:

```
INNER JOIN vi_lineup on vi_lineup.lineup_master_id = vi_lineup_master.lineup_master_id
```

Obviously, I am a newbie. I did search S.O. first but did not find a matching question. I'll keep looking and hope someone answers here. Thanks for any help.

A comment asked about the Weeks. The game is based on a weekly model and we number them sequentially. Here's a working query joining the tables and selecting records based on the weeks:

```
select * FROM vi_lineup LU 
INNER JOIN vi_lineup_master LM 
WHERE (LU.week > 4 and LU.week < 9)  
AND LU.lineup_master_id = LM.lineup_master_id 
Limit 0,148000;
```

What I would like to do now is Group the records by LM.UserID and sum the values in LU.Score
Thanks!

Comment: update your question add  the tables schema, a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: "match where 'Weeks' are between 5 and 8 inclusive" is very difficult to understand. An example of your data and expected results would be very helpful. Check out [this site for producing a nicely formatted table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) for here on SO (copy and pasting a table out of excel into that site and adding 4 leading spaces or a tab to each line will format nicely here on SO).

Comment: Thanks for looking. I will try to add the requested edits. Here is a query selecting on the Weeks field that is working. select * FROM vi_lineup LU INNER JOIN vi_lineup_master LM WHERE (LU.week > 4 and LU.week < 9)  AND LU.lineup_master_id = LM.lineup_master_id Limit 0,148000;

Answer (score 1):

You have not told us where userid or score comes from. But assuming you can clarify that yourself, the "basic" structure of the query will be like this:

```
SELECT
      ??.UserID, SUM(??.score) AS sum_score
FROM vi_lineup lu
INNER JOIN vi_lineup_master lm ON lu.lineup_master_id = lm.lineup_master_id
WHERE lu.week between 5 and 8
GROUP BY
      ??.UserID
```

You will need to replace each **??** with the correct table alias "lu" or "lm"

Comment: Thank you, very much. I got hold of the database developer today and he explained that the fields I was querying were in different schemas, but the UserID was in LM and Score was in LU.